# Keep history cached with WKWebView

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I am building a little app and I use a `WKWebView` to make the user able to navigate through web pages.

The problem I have is that whenever a user wants to go back to the previous visited page, this page has to be reloaded.

My question: is there a way to cache the content of every pages of the `WKWebView`'s history stack so navigating through the history wouldn't make all the pages load again ?

Answer (score 0):

The WKWebView stores it's own navigation history and according to the [class documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/), it can be navigated by using it's following member methods:

```
public func goToBackForwardListItem(item: WKBackForwardListItem) -> WKNavigation?

public func goBack() -> WKNavigation?

public func goForward() -> WKNavigation?
```

Using these methods to navigate through the history stack will behave in a similar manner as other browsers.  e.i. the position on the page will be kept, e.t.c...

Unfortunately, up to now, there is no way to save then reload this history stack.  So if you kill your app, there's no way to recreate a WKWebView with the history from a prior WKWebView.  Hopefully this will change in the future.